# SQL Query for joining more than 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql, join, inner-join

I just join 3 tables to get 1 field per table, what i want to ask is (since i'm not backend developer, this is company test) is query bellow is the correct way and fine? or is there more correct query to do this? and give explanation why query bellow is not good enought

```sql
SELECT Orders.OrderDate, Categories.CategoryName, OrderDetails.Quantity
  FROM Orders
 INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
 INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
 INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
```

Here is the database example link that i use for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Correct way to query join 3 or more tables in SQL

Comment: This is not a query-optimization question, so I removed that tag.

Comment: that is a short coming of the engine on that site, your query has non errors, install the develeloper edition of the sql server on your computer install ssms also and runthe queries locally

Comment: @nbk ? Can you see something not in the question?

Comment: @P.Salmon I edited with the database link, you can check

Comment: @P.Salmon run the query in w3schools and then run it at your home server, the query runs ok in w3 when you only have 2 tables but fails if you have two inner joins

Comment: @nbk ok, i'll try with xampp

Comment: you w3 link points to sql server, but ok xampp goes as well if you want to programm also php

Comment: @nbk itried in xampp and it also works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables definitions are simple, this looks OK to me. (You did not show us your table definitions so I am guessing about that.)

If your Products are in more than one Category, you may get more resultset rows that you expect.

I suggest you end the SQL statement with

```sql
ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate, Categories.CategoryName, OrderDetails.Quantity
```

to make your resultset easier to eyeball for correctness and unwanted duplicate rows.

Comment: For the database reference, i use database from here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all you can check that

Comment: @Muhammad Fadhil Akbar please include everything in the question(no links)